# React callback avoid re-render for child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have trouble to avoid re-renders.
Have a look in my simplified example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-satoshi-b3p1u?file=/src/App.js
Open the console. I have expensive and heavy code in the child hook which filters a big array (not in this lightweight example).
Every time "child has been rendered" get's printed into the console, my browser laggs and crashes if i do it too often.

There is **no state in Child**. I just use it to add a certain text piece (user can select from a big list of emojis and special chars) if i click to the textarea which needs a callback to communicate. I tried `React.useMemo()` and `useMemo()` but neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Add useMemo dependancies as needed,

```js
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ title: "default title", test: null });

  const childs = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <Child clickCallback={(x) => setData({ ...data, test: x })} />
    )
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Title: {data.title}</p>
      <p>Test: {data.test}</p>

      <input onChange={(x) => setData({ ...data, title: x.target.value })} />
      {childs}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Great! This looks like less effort compared to the solution of @salamaashoush . Is there also a way to concat with `setData({ ...data, test: data.test + x })` inside `useMemo()` if i want to append instead of replace?

Comment: Not sure what is mean by 'concat'

Comment: Sorry, i mistyped. I want to append "Text 2" to the data (for example "Test 1"). Let's take this as an example: I click on Test 1 and then on Test 2. "test" should be "Test 1 Test 2".

Comment: export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ title: "default title", test: null });

  const setMyData = useCallback(title => {
    const preVal = data.test;
    setData({...data, test: `${preVal} ${title}`});
  }, [setData, data]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Title: {data.title}</p>
      <p>Test: {data.test}</p>

      <input onChange={(x) => setData({ ...data, title: x.target.value })} />
      <Child clickCallback={(x) => setMyData(x)} />
    </div>
  );
}

Comment: Works, but this seems to re-render the child: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-mccarthy-58lfh?file=/src/App.js) . This will cause a lag.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `useCallback` to memoize functions/event handlers and avoid creating them every time, and also for child components you should use `memo` to rerender only if props have changed

App.js

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ title: "default title", test: null });
  const cb1 = useCallback(
    (x) => setData({ ...data, title: x.target.value }),
    []
  );
  const cb2 = useCallback((x) => setData({ ...data, test: x }), []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Title: {data.title}</p>
      <p>Test: {data.test}</p>

      <input onChange={cb1} />
      <Child clickCallback={cb2} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child.js

```
import { memo } from "react";

export default memo(function Child(props) {
  return (
    <>
      {console.log("child has been rendered")}
      <button onClick={() => props.clickCallback("test")}>test</button>
      <button onClick={() => props.clickCallback("test2")}>test2</button>
      <button onClick={() => props.clickCallback("test3")}>test3</button>
      <button onClick={() => props.clickCallback("test4")}>test4</button>
    </>
  );
});
```

check a working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-curran-tv502

Comment: This works great. But can i also append the callback to the existing data instead of "replacing" it? I want to keep the previous content and apply the new one to the back of it.

Comment: I don't get it. This does not re-render but neither appends. https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-lederberg-se6w1?file=/src/App.js